# How to check if a List in a ViewBag contains string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, collections, contains

I have a ViewBag that is a list which i create in the controller:

```
 List<string> listoflists = new List<string>();
```

it then gets filled with some string like for example:

```
listoflists.Add("java");
listoflists.Add("php");
listoflists.Add("C#");
```

Adding it to the ViewBag:
    ViewBag.listoflists = listoflists;

i then would like to check in my View if this contains a specific string:

```
@if(ViewBag.listoflists.contains("java")
{
// do html stuff
}
```

but when running this i get the following error:

**System.Collections.Generic.List does not contain a definition for contains**

What am i doing wrong, or how should i check if a list contains something in the View?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You might need to cast back to a list of strings:

```
@if (((IList<string>)ViewBag.listoflists).Contains("java")
{
    // do html stuff
}
```

Also notice that the `Contains` method starts with a capital `C`.

So as you can see using ViewBag in ASP.NET MVC is a complete crap leading to very ugly code in your views. For this reason it is strongly recommended to use view models which will contain all the necessary information of a specific view and also being strongly typed.

So cut this `ViewBag` crap and start using view models:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public IList<string> ListOfLists { get; set; }
}
```

that your controller action can populate and pass to the view:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new MyViewModel();
    List<string> listoflists = new List<string>();
    listoflists.Add("java");
    listoflists.Add("php");
    listoflists.Add("C#");
    model.ListOfLists = listoflists;
    return View(model);
}
```

and now you can have a strongly typed view to this model which will allow you to avoid the previous casting:

```
@model MyViewModel

@if (Model.ListOfLists.Contains("java"))
{
    // do html stuff
}
```

So basically every time you use ViewBag/ViewData in an ASP.NET MVC application an alarm should immediately ring in your head telling you: Man, what the hell, you are doing it wrong. Just use a view model in order to avoid transforming your views into an abominable mess of completely irrelevant C# language constructs like casting and stuff. Views are meant for displaying markup.

Answer (score 2):

`ViewBag` is a dynamic type, it does not know at compile time what is the actual type contained in the key `ViewBag.listoflists` you defined, you need to cast it to specific type and then you can call those methods on it:

```
@{

List<string> languages= ViewBag.listoflists as List<string>;
}
@if(languages.contains("java")
{
// do html stuff
}
```

Comment: You don't _need_ a cast - it just identifies the actual error at compile-time.

Comment: for compile time inteliisense, we need to cast i meant